# How to install SSL for Darwin Streaming Server on OS X Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, streaming, osx-mountain-lion, ssl

I downloaded [Darwin Streaming Server](http://dss.macosforge.org) and while I'm installing I want to enable SSL, but this requires that I have a valid streaming server SSL certificate installed.

How can I install an SSL certificate for Darwin Streaming Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OS X includes SSL out of the box:

```
$ openssl version 
OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
```

To create a self-signed certificate see this excellent article http://blog.case.edu/siva/2008/08/20/creating_selfsigned_certificate_for_darwin_streaming_server which basically says;

1. Generate a private key:

   ```
   $ openssl genrsa -des3 -out streamingadminserver.key 1024
   ```
2. Generate a CSR (Certificate Signing Request) (below, the important value is the common name. Replace `dss.yourdomain.local` with the name of your streaming server website):

   ```
   $ openssl req -new -key streamingadminserver.key -out streamingadminserver.csr

   Country Name (2 letter code) : US
   State or Province Name (full name) : CA
   Locality Name (eg, city) : Cupertino
   Organization Name (eg, company) : Apple Inc
   Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []: 
   Common Name (eg, your name or your server's hostname) []: dss.yourdomain.local
   Email Address []:martin.zahn@akadia.com
   Please enter the following 'extra' attributes to be sent with your certificate request
   A challenge password []:
   An optional company name []:
   ```
3. Remove passphrase from key:

   ```
   $ cp streamingadminserver.key streamingadminserver.passwd.key
   $ openssl rsa -in streamingadminserver.passwd.key -out streamingadminserver.key
   ```
4. Generate a self-signed certificate:

   ```
   $ openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -in streamingadminserver.csr -signkey streamingadminserver.key -out streamingadminserver.pem
   ```

Now you have a self-signed certificate named `streamingadminserver.pem` valid for 10 years. Now install it like this (from http://manuals.info.apple.com/en/quicktimestreamingsrvradminguide.pdf):

> Install the certificate in `/Library/QuickTimeStreaming/streamingadminserver.pem` 
>   (for Mac OS X) with the information from your certificate file.
>
> For Windows, install the certificate in `c:\Program Files\Darwin Streaming Server\streamingadminserver.pem`.
>
> In other supported platforms, install it in /`etc/streaming/
>   streamingadminserver.pem`.

Notice that it will generate an error in the browser. You will have to show the certificate and check the box *Always trust* to get rid of the error.

To extract information from your new certificate type:

```
$ openssl x509 -text -in streamingadminserver.pem
```

For more information on the `openssl` command line see this howto: http://www.madboa.com/geek/openssl/.

Comment: I already installed OSX server and made a self signed certificate, but that didn't help. I also did everything you posted, but still i get the message: SSL is not available on this computer. Please make sure that the Net::SSLeay perl module, OpenSSL, and a signed SSL certificate are installed.

Comment: I added information on how to install the SSL certificate. Notice that the certificate **must** be named `streamingadminserver.pem`. OpenSSL and Net::SSLeay are both already included in 10.8.2.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the following error trying secure admin : (Error 113 (net::ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH): Unknown error.)

Change lasts steps of described process :

1
- when self signing do :

```
#openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -in streamingadminserver.csr -signkey streamingadminserver.key -out streamingadminserver.crt
```

2-then do :

```
#cat streamingadminserver.key streamingadminserver.crt > streamingadminserver.pem
```

3-finish by (UNIX) :

```
#cp streamingadminserver.pem /etc/streaming
```